# R: creating a longitudinal dataset using tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I am looking to generate a longitudinal dataset. I have generated my pat numbers and treatment groups:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(420)
Pat_TNO <- 1001:1618

data.frame(Pat_TNO = Pat_TNO) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    trt = rbinom(1, 1, 0.5)
  )
```

My timepoints (in days) are:

```
timepoint_weeks <- c(seq(2, 12, 2), 16, 20, 24, 52)
timepoint_days <- 7 * timepoint_weeks
```

How can I pivot this dataset using the vector `timepoint_days`, so I have 10 rows per participant and column names `Pat_TNO`, `trt`, `timepoint_days`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unnest` function from `tidyr` to achieve what you want.

Here is the code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(420)
Pat_TNO <- 1001:1618

x <- data.frame(Pat_TNO = Pat_TNO) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    trt = rbinom(1, 1, 0.5)
  )

timepoint_weeks <- c(seq(2, 12, 2), 16, 20, 24, 52)
timepoint_days <- 7 * timepoint_weeks

x %>% 
  mutate(timepoint_days = list(timepoint_days)) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 6,180 × 3
   Pat_TNO   trt timepoint_days
     <int> <int>          <dbl>
 1    1001     1             14
 2    1001     1             28
 3    1001     1             42
 4    1001     1             56
 5    1001     1             70
 6    1001     1             84
 7    1001     1            112
 8    1001     1            140
 9    1001     1            168
10    1001     1            364
# … with 6,170 more rows
```

Here I used the `mutate` function to add a column with a list containing `timepoint_days` in every row. And then `unnest` collapses each row to get 10 rows per participant.